# Removing Duplicates in View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, duplicates

The code was working fine. Today morning I see that after the automated job ran, it ended up populating duplicates. After investigation, I find out that the fact tables do no contain duplicates, but one of the views does. How do I remove the duplicate views? The code is as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         fact.Incident.Number, fact.Incident.Activity_Due, fact.Incident.Additional_Assignee_List, fact.Incident.Approval_History, fact.Incident.Approval_Set, fact.Incident.Business_Duration, fact.Incident.Business_Service, 
                         fact.Incident.Business_STC, fact.Incident.Calendar_Duration, fact.Incident.Calendar_STC, fact.Incident.Caused_By, fact.Incident.Close_Code, fact.Incident.Close_Notes, fact.Incident.Cmdb_CI AS Hide, 
                         fact.Incident.Comments, fact.Incident.Comments_And_Work_Notes, fact.Incident.Contract, fact.Incident.Contact_Type, fact.Incident.Correlation_Display, fact.Incident.Correlation_ID, fact.Incident.Description, 
                         fact.Incident.Due_Date, fact.Incident.Escalation, fact.Incident.Expected_Start, fact.Incident.Follow_Up, fact.Incident.Group_List, fact.Incident.Impact, fact.Incident.Incident_State, fact.Incident.Knowledge, 
                         fact.Incident.Made_SLA, fact.Incident.Notify, fact.Incident.[Order], fact.Incident.Parent, fact.Incident.Parent_Incident, fact.Incident.Priority, fact.Incident.Problem_ID, fact.Incident.Reassignment_Count, 
                         fact.Incident.Rejection_goto, fact.Incident.Reopen_Count, fact.Incident.RFC, fact.Incident.Service_Offering AS [To hide], fact.Incident.Severity, fact.Incident.Short_Description, fact.Incident.Skills, 
                         fact.Incident.SLA_Due, fact.Incident.State, fact.Incident.Subcategory, fact.Incident.Sys_Class_Name, fact.Incident.Sys_Domain, fact.Incident.Companies, fact.Incident.Sys_ID, fact.Incident.Sys_Mod_Count, 
                         fact.Incident.Time_Worked, fact.Incident.u_Approver, fact.Incident.u_Bomgar, fact.Incident.u_Comments_Updated, fact.Incident.u_Confidential, fact.Incident.u_Escalated_To, fact.Incident.u_Feedback, 
                         fact.Incident.u_First_Category, fact.Incident.u_First_CI, fact.Incident.u_Group_Internal, fact.Incident.u_Has_Attachments, fact.Incident.u_ManagementGroup, fact.Incident.u_Metric_Timeline, fact.Incident.u_Noted, 
                         fact.Incident.u_One_To_One_Training, fact.Incident.u_Prev_Short_Desc, fact.Incident.u_Priority_Changed, fact.Incident.u_Problem_Candidate, fact.Incident.u_Proccess_Sync, fact.Incident.u_Response_Time, 
                         fact.Incident.u_Solution, fact.Incident.u_Type, fact.Incident.u_Update_KB, fact.Incident.u_Vendor, fact.Incident.u_Vendor_Number, fact.Incident.Upon_Approval, fact.Incident.Upon_Reject, fact.Incident.Urgency, 
                         fact.Incident.User_Input, fact.Incident.Variables, fact.Incident.Vendor, fact.Incident.Vendor_Closed_At, fact.Incident.Vendor_Opened_At, fact.Incident.Vendor_Point_of_Contact, fact.Incident.Vendor_Resolved_at, 
                         fact.Incident.Vendor_Ticket, fact.Incident.Watch_List, fact.Incident.Work_End, fact.Incident.Work_Notes, fact.Incident.Work_Notes_List, fact.Incident.Work_Start, fact.Incident.Table_Insert_Date, 
                         fact.Incident.Table_Update_Date, fact.Incident.Link, fact.Incident.[Updated By Email], fact.Incident.[Priority Name], fact.Incident.[Severity Name], fact.Incident.[Urgency Name], fact.Incident.[State Name], 
                         dim.dimDate.Day AS [Closed at Day], dim.dimDate.WeekDayName AS [Closed at Day Name], dim.dimDate.IsWeekend AS [Closed at is weekend], dim.dimDate.Month AS [Closed at month], 
                         dim.dimDate.MonthName AS [Closed at month name], dim.dimDate.Quarter AS [Closed at quarter], dim.dimDate.Year AS [Closed at year], dim.dimDate.MMYYYY AS [Closed at MMYYYY], 
                         dimDate_1.Day AS [Opened at day], dimDate_1.WeekDayName AS [Opened at Day Name], dimDate_1.IsWeekend AS [Opened  isweekend], dimDate_1.Month AS [Opened Month], 
                         dimDate_1.MonthName AS [Opened Month Name], dimDate_1.Quarter AS [Opened Quarter], dimDate_1.Year AS [Opened Year], dimDate_1.MMYYYY AS [Opened MMYYYY], 
                         dim.dimLocation.city AS [Location City], dim.dimLocation.country AS [Location Country], dim.dimLocation.state AS [Location State], dim.dimLocation.IsBureau AS [Location IsBureau], 
                         dim.dimLocation.IsNewsroom AS [Location IsNewsroom], dim.dimLocation.contact AS [Location Contact], dim.dimLocation.Location, dimEmployee_2.[Full Name] AS [Caller ID Name], 
                         dimEmployee_2.EmployeeID AS [Caller ID (Employee ID)], dimEmployee_2.[Email Address] AS [Caller ID Email Address], dimEmployee_2.[Job Title] AS [Caller ID Job Title], 
                         dimEmployee_2.Department AS [Caller ID Department], dimEmployee_2.[Mobile Phone] AS [Caller ID Mobile Phone], dimEmployee_2.[Business Phone] AS [[Caller ID]] Business Phone], 
                         dimEmployee_2.Company AS [Caller ID Company], dimDate_2.Date AS [Created On Date], dimDate_2.Day AS [Created On Day], dimDate_2.WeekDayName AS [Created On Day Name], 
                         dimDate_2.IsWeekend AS [Created On IsWeekend], dimDate_2.IsHolidayQatar AS [Created On IsholidayQatar], dimDate_2.Month AS [Created Month], dimDate_2.MonthName AS [Created MonthName], 
                         dimDate_2.Quarter AS [Created Quarter], dimDate_2.Year AS [Created Year], dimDate_2.MMYYYY AS [Created MMYYYY], fact.Incident.Active, dimDate_3.Day AS [Updated Day], 
                         dimDate_3.WeekDayName AS [Updated Day Name], dimDate_3.IsWeekend AS [Updated IsWeekend], dimDate_3.Month AS [Updated Month], dimDate_3.MonthName AS [Updated Month Name], 
                         dimDate_3.Quarter AS [Updated Quarter], dimDate_3.Year AS [Updated Year], dimDate_3.MMYYYY AS [Updated MMYYYY], fact.Incident.Closed_At AS [Closed at Date], 
                         fact.Incident.Opened_at AS [Opened at date], fact.Incident.Sys_Updated_On AS Updated, servicenow.staging_category.u_name AS Category, fact.Incident.u_Category, 
                         servicenow.staging_business_service.name AS Service_Offering, servicenow.staging_configuration_item.name AS CMDB_CI, fact.Incident.Child_Incidents, 
                         dimEmployee_2.[User Primary Group] AS [Caller Primary Group], user_1.name AS [Opened By Full Name], user_1.employee_number AS [Opened By Employee ID], user_1.email AS [Opened By Email Address], 
                         user_1.title AS [Opened By Job Title], user_1.Department AS [Opened By Department], user_1.mobile_phone AS [Opened By Mobile Phone], user_1.Company AS [Opened By Company], 
                         user_1.u_primary_group AS [Opened By Primary Group], fact.[user].name AS [Closed By], fact.[user].email AS [Closed By Email Address], fact.[user].title AS [Closed By Job Title], 
                         fact.[user].Department AS [Closed By Department], fact.[user].Company AS [Closed By Company], fact.[user].mobile_phone AS [Closed By Mobile Phone], fact.[user].phone AS [Closed By Business Phone], 
                         fact.[user].u_primary_group AS [Closed By Primary Group], fact.Incident.[Assignment Group], fact.Incident.[Opened By Email] AS [Assignment Group Manager], 
                         fact.Incident.[Caller ID Email] AS [Assignment Group Email], user_2.u_primary_group AS [Assigned To Primary Group], user_2.employee_number AS [Employee ID(Assigned to)], 
                         fact.Incident.[Assigned to Email] AS [Email Address (Assigned to)], user_2.name AS [Assigned to]
FROM            fact.Incident LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         fact.[user] AS user_2 ON fact.Incident.[Assigned to Email] = user_2.email LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         fact.[user] ON fact.Incident.[Closed By Email] = fact.[user].email LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         fact.[user] AS user_1 ON fact.Incident.[Opened By Email] = user_1.email LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         servicenow.staging_configuration_item ON fact.Incident.Cmdb_CI = servicenow.staging_configuration_item.sys_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         servicenow.staging_business_service ON fact.Incident.Service_Offering = servicenow.staging_business_service.sys_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         servicenow.staging_category ON fact.Incident.u_Category = servicenow.staging_category.sys_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dim.dimDate ON fact.Incident.[Closed At Datekey] = dim.dimDate.DateKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dim.dimDate AS dimDate_1 ON fact.Incident.[Opened At Datekey] = dimDate_1.DateKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dim.dimLocation ON fact.Incident.Location = dim.dimLocation.Location LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dim.dimDate AS dimDate_2 ON fact.Incident.[Created Datekey] = dimDate_2.DateKey LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dim.dimEmployee AS dimEmployee_2 ON fact.Incident.[Caller ID Email] = dimEmployee_2.[Email Address] LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dim.dimDate AS dimDate_3 ON fact.Incident.[Updated Datekey] = dimDate_3.DateKey
```

I'm using the following code to check the duplicates:
SELECT count(sys_id),number FROM [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[Requests Hierarchy View] group by (sys_id),number having count(sys_id)>1

The sample result dataset is as follows:

(No column name)    number 2    REQ0035412 2    REQ0032389 2    REQ0031000 2    REQ0047666 2 REQ0039400 2   REQ0030341 2    REQ0044462 2    REQ0026023 2    REQ0044207 2    REQ0020707 2 REQ0028762 2   REQ0043741 2    REQ0016740 2    REQ0027287 2    REQ0029590 2    REQ0050115 2 REQ0047027 2   REQ0018817 2    REQ0042548 2    REQ0025433 2    REQ0030387 2    REQ0042481 2 REQ0039159 2   REQ0042938 2    REQ0042648 2    REQ0043439 2    REQ0012954 2    REQ0031663 2 REQ0035056 2   REQ0021218 2    REQ0052394 2    REQ0034172 2    REQ0022032 2    REQ0013801 2 REQ0051336 2   REQ0013728 2    REQ0017371 2    REQ0047735 2    REQ0027745 2    REQ0045043 2 REQ0032863

Thera are a total of 716 duplicate rows. However, I'm sharing just a few as sample data

The sys_id is the unique identifier !

Thank you for reading and for any help you can provide!

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT returns no duplicate rows. Duplicate column values can be expected however.

Comment: SELECT count(sys_id),number
FROM [ALJAZEERA\Naeemf].[Requests Hierarchy View]
group by (sys_id),number
having count(sys_id)>1

Comment: (No column name) number
2 REQ0035412
2 REQ0032389
2 REQ0031000
2 REQ0047666
2 REQ0039400
2 REQ0030341
2 REQ0044462
2 REQ0026023
2 REQ0044207
2 REQ0020707
2 REQ0028762
2 REQ0043741
2 REQ0016740
2 REQ0027287
2 REQ0029590
2 REQ0050115
2 REQ0047027
2 REQ0018817
2 REQ0042548
2 REQ0025433
2 REQ0030387
2 REQ0042481
2 REQ0039159
2 REQ0042938
2 REQ0042648
2 REQ0043439
2 REQ0012954
2 REQ0031663
2 REQ0035056
2 REQ0021218
2 REQ0052394
2 REQ0034172
2 REQ0022032
2 REQ0013801
2 REQ0051336
2 REQ0013728
2 REQ0017371
2 REQ0047735
2 REQ0027745
2 REQ0045043
2 REQ0032863

Comment: Thera are a total of 716 duplicate rows. However, I'm sharing just a few as sample data

Comment: If there's a better way to show you the sample data, let me know. I'm new to this platform. Thanks.

Comment: Edit the question instead.

Comment: BTW, one-to-many relations usually end up with duplicate id's.

Comment: @jarlh: As advised, I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Display properly your question and what u want?

Comment: Hi @DipakRathod: I think the question is elaborate enough. However, if you'd like to understand further, kindly specify what is required in the question and I'll add to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are not joining your dimensions on a unique key and there are multiple rows in the dimension with this key value. Are these slowly changing dimensions (type 2 probably)? Check dim.dimEmployee, are there rows with the same e-mail address?

```
select [Email Address], count(*) from dim.dimEmployee group by [Email Address] having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Just checked. No duplicates for email address.

Comment: Check the others. If your fact table doesn't have the duplicates, then some of the joins is the reason. Try to remove the joins one by one and see when the duplicated rows will disappear.

Comment: This will take some time :-)